# synonyms analyzer and PhoneticAnalyzer in Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, phonetics

Does someone knows how to use Phonetic Analyzer and synonyms analyzer. I'm not finding a good tutorial that explains this well??

Answer (score 1):

Any question in specific? I believe that the Hibernate Search documentation provides enough information to get started:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e393

Also, you may want to check the unit test suite, which contains some usage examples for all aspects of Hibernate Search, including Analyzers:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/hibernate-search/src/test/java/org/hibernate/search/test/analyzer/solr/Team.java

Also, if you are starting with Hibernate Search, I highly recommend Hibernate Search in Action. It provides great in-depth information about Hibernate Search (including some nice things about Lucene).